# what is the meaning of "phlossofeh"?

Tags: meaning

Could you please tell me, what does "phlossofeh" in this sentence:

> Her patrician tones (she always spoke of "phlosoffeh" and "litch-cha") limited her appeal...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about non-standard, in fact one-off, phonetic representations.

Comment: If the quote that the OP was inquiring about came from a published source (as opposed to being his own invention) would that not argue that this was indeed about a standard part of English, namely the mechanism used to convey non-standard pronunciations in a standard text?  Of course he was not asking about the general mechanism, but rather a specific usage of it.

Answer (score 3):

These are humourous phonetic spelling of "philosopy" and "literature".
As a speaker of American English it sounds like a high-class Boston accent.  If it's from the UK I can not be sure.

Might be helpful to know the source of the quote

Comment: If it's from the UK, it does sound like a good rendering of very old-fashioned upper-class speech.  The vowels clipped to nothing and the open E at the end of 'philosophy' sound very like our old ruling class.

Comment: I believe that the word "patrician" is much more commonly applied to the American upper class than to the British, which supports your "Bostonian" theory.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a spelling of "philosophy" (and "literature") intended to evoke a certain way of speaking ("Her patrician tones").

Part of writing is sometimes modifying the spelling of words to evoke certain pronunciations or dialects. See, for example, the way Mark Twain wrote dialogue in *Huckleberry Finn*.

Comment: Could you please tell what is the pronunciation?

Comment: Judging from the spelling, the first vowel is elided, combining the first two syllables into one: "phlo-" the middle syllable "-so-" doesn't seem to be altered. The final syllable is rendered as "-feh", indicating that the terminal vowel is degraded from a long 'e', as most speakers would pronounce is, into more of a schwa sound.

Comment: Perhaps someone more knowledgeable than I could render this pronunciation in IPA, or some other phonetic alphabet. I'm just sounding out the spelling as I read it. :)

Comment: This is my IPA rendering: /ˈflɔsəfɛ/